# ActiveModel - Validation failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activemodel

I got an error `Validation failed` when I try to update a field and I'm not sure to understand how the `validates` works

I have a `Booking` model defined as below:

```rb
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  include ActiveModel::Dirty

  validates :requester_status,
            inclusion: { in: %w[pending approved cancelled expired] }

  validates :host_status,
            inclusion: { in: %w[pending approved declined cancelled flexible_dates expired] }

  validates :start_at, date: { after: Date.yesterday }, presence: true
  validates :end_at, date: { after: :start_at }, presence: true
end
```

I defined a function to update the `hosts_status` and `requester_status` as below:

```rb
def self.set_expired
  pending_bookings = Booking.where(host_status: 'pending').where('end_at < ?', Date.today)

  pending_bookings.each do |pending_booking|
    pending_booking.host_status = 'expired'
    pending_booking.requester_status = 'expired'
    pending_booking.save!
  end
end
```

I'm only updating `host_status` and `requester_status` and I got the error: 
`ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Start at must be after 2019-01-07` whereas this field is not updated.

So I'm not sure to really understand what's happening

Comment: When you try to save a record all validators have to be valid - not only the validators on columns you actually changed. If this is not what you want then you will have to write your own custom validation that is able to handle complex conditions or edge-cases.

Comment: @spickermann so the only way to avoid this is to add `on: :create` ?

Comment: what @spickermann said, plus, if you don't want to run some validations when updating a record, then specify that in the validation with `on: :create`, for more information about that, just go to https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates

Comment: Careful with `after: Date.yesterday` too. `Date.yesterday` will be evaluated when the class is being evaluated, not when the validation is being run. You might want `after:  ->{ Date.yesterday }` to ensure that `Date.yesterday` is evaluated at the right time.

Comment: I need your server  log